# Codeigniter: this->db->set is not working with value from post

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Hi I have a problem with my **$this->db->set** as I need to subtract the value of **feestudent_amount** on **payment** which is inserted as **$payment = $this->input->post('subpaymentamount')[$x];**

So my query looks like this

```
for($x = 1; $x <= count($this->input->post('subparticulars')); $x++) {

   $feetype = $this->input->post('subparticulars')[$x];
   $student = $this->input->post('substudentid');
   $schoolyear = $this->input->post('subschoolyeardata');

   $payment = $this->input->post('subpaymentamount')[$x];

   $this->db->set('feestudent_amount', '`feestudent_amount` - $payment', FALSE); // I'm having problem in here.

   $this->db->where(array('feetype_id' => $feetype, 'student_id' => $student, 'schoolyear_id' => $schoolyear));

   $status2 = $this->db->update('tbl_feestudent');    
 } // /.for

return ($status2 === true ? true : false);
```

The only problem I have is in this line of codes.

```
$payment = $this->input->post('subpaymentamount')[$x];

$this->db->set('feestudent_amount', '`feestudent_amount` - $payment', FALSE);
```

others works fine as I've tried inserting specific values in $payment like this.

```
$this->db->set('feestudent_amount', '`feestudent_amount` - 5000', FALSE);
```

and it subtracts 5000 from the feestudent amount

How can I insert the value from the **$this->input->post('subpaymentamount')[$x]** in the code where will I subtract it the **feestudent_amount**.

Comment: Use this `$this->db->set('feestudent_amount', 'feestudent_amount -'. $payment, FALSE);`

Comment: thanks It worked but I come up with other answer also, different from this one.